# On the personal identity of a self aware artificial intelligence

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, artificial-intelligence

Philosophers have discussed the question of personal identity of humans, including humans uploaded to hypothetical computers; but are there any notable discussions of the problems of personal identity of a future strong artificial intelligence (outside the context of uploaded minds)?

Comment: Would not the same problems exists if the ai was truly ai? Is artificial intelligence not the mere replication of the human experience through the digital medium as opposed to a biological one?

Answer (score 2):

> Philosophers have discussed the question of personal identity of humans, including humans uploaded to hypothetical computers; but are there any notable discussions of the problems of personal identity of a future strong artificial intelligence (outside the context of uploaded minds)?

I'm not a philosopher; I'm doing research on general cognitive theory which includes both human and machine cognition.

- Computers are based on Church-Turing theory. This theory does include
  AI but does not include things like understanding and reasoning which
  humans do everyday.
- Human-level comprehension and reasoning requires a different theory
  from Church-Turing and hardware that is different from a computer.
- Even with such hardware, it would be impossible to use a machine like
  this to transfer or even duplicate your mind.
- With a general theory of cognition it should be possible to build a
  machine that is conscious with similar comprehension and reasoning to
  a human.
- Since such a machine would be self-aware, you are correct that this
  could lead to psychological problems for the machine agent.

Comment: Please elaborate. Why do you claim that "Human-level comprehension and reasoning requires a different theory from Church-Turing"? What kind of general theory of cognition are you talking of? would it be possible to model such a future machine mathematically? suppose we build it. would it not follow the rules of quantum mechanics? if it does, then what should prevent (in principle, not in practice) a Turing machine from simulating it to arbitrary accuracy? Can you provide some details on your research and institute?

Comment: I have evidence for it. This is my field of research. A theory that would explain how human reasoning evolved from unintelligent round worms to humans, that would explain how human reasoning works and how it could be replicated non-biologically. If the theory is completed then a human-level machine could be designed. I have no idea why you are talking about quantum mechanics. It hasn't had any effect on the research I've done. There is nothing in Church-Turing that allows for defining or replicating human understanding. So, how would you add that? Magic?

Comment: My research. I created knowledge theory which provides a foundation for cognitive theory. I can explain awareness, learning, understanding, and problem solving. The theory covers things like worry and attention blindness. It isn't finished though. If I do finish it by 2019 then I'll probably publish it along with knowledge theory in 2021.

Comment: Turing does not deal with thinking nor understanding simply because there was no and there still is no accepted definition for them. That is the point of his paper "Computing Machinery and Intelligence". I don't understand, are you proposing a way to build machines that can not be simulated even in principle by Turing machines? i.e. machines that are not Turing equivalent?

Comment: @scientious, are you an academic working in a field with peer-review practices, in which you plan to publish the theory?

Comment: I'm not an academic; I'm a scientist. Your next sentence is word salad. I don't know how a field would have peer review unless you talking about agreement. Maybe you were trying to ask if I plan to publish in a professional journal which of course would be peer reviewed before publication. No, the theory wouldn't fit in a journal article. It will probably take 700 pages.

Comment: @nir 
>Turing does not deal with thinking nor understanding simply because there was no and there still is no accepted definition for them.  

Your assertion is partly true. I have been able to define understanding.

> are you proposing a way to build machines that can not be simulated even in principle by Turing machines? i.e. machines that are not Turing equivalent?     

Yes.

Comment: but that means the output of such a machine cannot be computed, doesn't it? and you write above your work is not affected by qm, so I don't understand. suppose this machine is built of ropes and cog-wheels or electric circuits, or light, etc..., and its functionality does not rely on quantum effects, which can be computed as far as I know anyway, then how would it output anything that we cannot compute?

Comment: @nir You seem very confused about computation. There is no computation for a random number. The closest that computation can get are pseudo-random numbers. Things like dice rolls and mechanical slot machines are not computable even though the behavior of the components can be described with simple physics. The best predictive simulation I can think of would be something like the large cannon on WWII battleships. They were accurate to about 50 yards at 16 miles. Bomb drops from altitude cannot be computed with pinpoint accuracy, so today we use GPS guidance with active steering.

Comment: @nir So, next you are going to ask me if the brain can be simulated. It can be to some extent but not to an accurate enough degree to duplicate thought, decisions, and desires.

Comment: Please avoid condescending and insulting. my questions are fair and no one is forcing you to answer them. How do random events help transcend Turing equivallence? As far as I know they don't. Secondly, are you proposing to build a machine that can compute the exact outcome of random events? If not, then how are all of your examples relevant? Take your example of dice as a simple case. Can't a deterministic simulation produce dice roll that cannot be practically distinguished from "real" dice roll?

Comment: Also, in the case of dice roll or in any other physical case why can't a deterministic machine simulate it in principle, if not in practice, to any desired degree of accuracy? Do you not distinguish between these two categories?

Comment: @nir You believe that pointing out your confusion about computation is an insult? Church-Turing does not include randomness. It cannot be simulated and has nothing to do with the theory. When you include it you are switching to probabilistic computation which is no longer determinant. And, no, I said nothing about building a machine to compute random events.

Comment: @nir >Can't a deterministic simulation produce dice roll that cannot be practically distinguished from "real" dice roll?

** I don't know how else to explain this to you. There is no such thing as a simulation of a random event. It doesn't exist. The closest you can get to it computationally is a pseudo-random number generator. **

Comment: I did not mean that a random number can be computed - I did not write such a thing above. what I meant is the following, suppose a real white-cube-with-black-dots dice is rolled 5000 times - do you claim that we cannot in principle produce a physical simulation of a modeled white-cube-with-black-dots dice that is rolled 5000 times, such that it cannot be practically distinguished from the real dice roll? More generally, I refer to the Church–Turing–Deutsch principle according to which "a universal computing device can simulate every physical process."

Comment: In that sense, how can the machine you are conceiving of escape simulability by a Turing machine? I would like to note that if you were to browse through some of the things I have written on this website it would become evident to you that I in fact believe brains are not computable - that there is an aspect to our consciousness that cannot possibly arise in a computing system and that therefore Deutsch and others must be wrong.

Comment: in that respect I am genuinely curious about what you claim to be doing. I believe that to pull it off you should be someone in the caliber of Newton, Galileo, Einstein and Feynman combined. so you are either such a person or an idiot, which is naturally the more likely possibility by far, but being a curious optimist I do not actually know which possibility is in fact true, so I would be glad to learn more about what you do.

Comment: @nir What you are talking about is only a conjecture by Deutsch and there are some problems with it. CTD would be valid only if physical processes are simpler than mathematics since this area is already restricted by Goedel's Incompleteness Theorem. If physical processes are equal or greater in complexity then CTD is false. And, unfortunately, I already have a proof of this.

Comment: @nir Well, it could be Dunning-Kruger. The problem with that hypothesis is that I am familiar with existing theories and research. People with DK avoid challenges to their ideas. Secondly, although I had intuitions I knew that they were of no value unless they could be proved. People with DK value their intuitions; they typically leap to conclusions without solid proof. It took me almost two years to make progress and I'm still working on the problem five years later. People with DK tend to reach conclusions quickly with no real work and then consider it done.

Comment: @nir It could be a faulty, shallow, or overly simplistic theory. Mine was built up in pieces. As I would make progress I would realize more of what I didn't know. There was never a point when I came up with a simple idea that suddenly seemed to explain everything. Secondly, the theory conforms to evidence. This includes things like focal blindness, PTSD, and worry. Theories like global workspace and integrated information theory don't address these things at all.

Comment: @nir Am I like Newton? Not exactly, because Newton relied heavily on math in which he was very adept. However, Newton's advances in calculus and gravitation relied on work done by Kepler so I guess we would be alike in that regard. The closest would probably be Charles Darwin. A major difference is that Darwin used specimens that were unknown before he collected them on the Beagle, whereas today there is a vast amount of evidence. Also, major work on Evolution did not begin until 1910 and with the hypothesis that DNA carried genetic material wasn't created until 1927.

Comment: @scientious, thanks for these comments. you write "If physical processes are equal or greater in complexity then CTD is false. And, unfortunately, I already have a proof of this." - is it possible for you to provide some details? it is interesting that you bring up Godel.

Answer (score -3):

A human is a whimsical being: sometimes it can act against even it's own mental programming. From what we can gather, it is impossible to set a straight rule to what a human does or feels, and for a computer to try to simulate that would be like making it choose a random number from 1~10, except that each number has equal probability: but the human choice does not. The human also acts based on it's feelings: a computer could be programmed to respond to certain feelings that can be triggered by some sort of observation/emotional simulation program that is fit to the target human's mental/physical state, but those feelings won't be real. It may seem like an oddball feeling, but the reality of what someone feels can make a world of a difference. For example, imagine your mother telling you that she loves you. You know she means it, you know she loves you with all her heart. But take away the realness, the sincerity of those words. What are they now? Even if the words come to your ears, they wouldn't touch your heart. Humans are emotional creatures. As much as we are lying, thieving, cold, heartless, ruthless, selfish, conceited, self-serving, spoiled, cowardly creatures, we also have an unbelievable love for the truth, at least from the emotions of another significant being. Computers can't simulate truth: only physical demonstration. This will block the computer from being aware of the identity that they were uploaded to simulate: they may physically act like the identity, but they won't emotionally be able to contain the complexity of the human brain. Of course, this is talking about the first two or three decades of the 21st century. Maybe computers will develop new hardware to make itself notice it's uploaded identity and perhaps even contain the human soul, but for now, I don't think it's possible.

But hey, that's just my theory.

Comment: philosophy of personal identity is about something completely different - take a look here: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! A few bits of feedback: (1) the community style is generally not about presenting things as "my theory is X", (2), the long block of text is challenging to read, can you try breaking up into paragraphs?